# unit of work design pattern - example without entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I'm trying to learn the Unit of Work and Repository patterns and wanted to do some samples at the same time.  However, whatever I'm finding online always uses Entity Framework.

What would the Unit of Work and Repository patterns look like if not specific to Entity Framework?  It is a little difficult to discern what aspects are part of the pattern and what are a side affect of integrating with EF.

Comment: It should be fairly easy to find repositories implemented with Mocks.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/377435/Mocking-the-generic-repository

Comment: Pluralsight has a unit of work demo.  The explanation uses ADO.NET.  This is a paid site: http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=patterns-library&highlight=scott-allen_pattern-unitofwork!scott-allen_pattern-repository*4#pattern-unitofwork

Comment: I have attempted to reword the question so that it is neither a request for an "off-site resource" nor specifically "asking for code"(although an answer certainly could use code to demonstrate the pattern and or link to a resource with the obligatory summary), but instead more focused about learning about the Unit of Work and Repository patterns in **general** as opposed to being specific to the EF technology.

Comment: since it is closed. no idea why since this is a genuine question. So I answer it in couple of comments.. 1) EmployeeRepository.Save(employeeObject) // saves directly to DB 2) SalaryRepository.Save(salaryObject) //saves directly to DB. But there is a problem, these both should happen in one single transaction. Which means both repositories cannot store it directly to DB. Instead they need to put it in a collection(inside unit of work) which is injected and shared by all repositories.

Comment: And once all transactions are done (delete/update/create) then this collection(inside unit of work) is taken to DB in one go(outside of repositories by the unit of work code)! If there is error then whole transactions are rolled back. So how would you implement the collection? how would you store what needs to be done with each item in the collection (update/delete/create). If it is update, how do you know the old and new value.

Comment: Good luck with implementing yourself the object model collection or just use ObjectContext! ObjectContext or DataContext of EF can easily be passed to repositories. Repositories add/delete/update the model in ObjectContext. Later unitofwork commits the ObjectContext!! in one go!!

Comment: And here I have explained using unit of work pattern and using EF as a collection object inside unit of work. So you get best of both worlds. No need to replace unit of work with EF!

Comment: I wasn't trying to get rid of EF, just wanted to see a sample without it.  Your explanation helped.

Comment: This question should be re-opened now since it has been reworded to fit within the rules. The reasons listed for why it was originally off-topic are no longer valid. It is now just asking for a generic and high-level explanation of what the "Unit of Work" and "Repository" patterns are without having to resort to concepts exclusive to Entity Framework to do so.

Comment: If one has to find the best questions on this site, its mostly going to be the ones closed as off topic

Comment: @user20358 Yep. This was the first result on after I googled _"unit of work pattern without entity framework"_. A closed thread.

I really hate people sometimes.